# Swift - How can I group value array (from dictonary) to multiple section

Tags: swift, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner in Swift. How can I group array list from dictionary? I tried, but it show all list into one section. I can't group, list, sort and show list by the same group.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjZZU.png)

But I can do like this, 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhv9K.png)

Here's the code for Todolist array

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


struct TodoList {
    var title:String!
    var content:String!
    var username:String!
    var dateLabel:String!
    var ref : FIRDatabaseReference?
    var key: String!
    var picNoteStringUrl : String!
    var userImageViewStringUrl : String!
    var postId: String!



    init(title:String,content:String,username:String,picNoteStringUrl : String,userImageViewStringUrl : String,postId: String,dateLabel:String,key:String="") {
        self.title=title
        self.content=content
        self.username = username
        self.dateLabel = dateLabel
        self.key=key
        self.userImageViewStringUrl = userImageViewStringUrl
        self.picNoteStringUrl = picNoteStringUrl
        self.postId = postId
        self.ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    }

    init(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
       let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
          title = value?["title"] as! String
          content = value?["content"] as! String
          username = value?["username"] as! String
          postId = value?["postId"] as! String
          picNoteStringUrl = value?["picNoteStringUrl"] as! String
          userImageViewStringUrl = value?["userImageViewStringUrl"] as! String
          dateLabel = value?["dateLabel"] as! String

            key = snapshot.key
            ref = snapshot.ref


    }


    func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {

        return ["title": title as AnyObject, "content": content as AnyObject,"username": username as AnyObject,"picNoteStringUrl":picNoteStringUrl as AnyObject,"userImageViewStringUrl": userImageViewStringUrl as AnyObject,"postId":postId as AnyObject,"dateLabel" : dateLabel as AnyObject]
    }

}
```

And here's my code for TableViewController

```
class TodoListTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    var storageRef: FIRStorageReference!



    var databaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!

    var todoArray:[TodoList] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser==nil{


             let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
            self.present(vc,animated: true,completion: nil)

        }

        else{


       let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid         
       let  databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("allTasks").child(uid!)


        databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            var newItems = [TodoList]()



            for item in snapshot.children {


                let newTodo = TodoList(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                let letter = newTodo.dateLabel


            newItems.insert(newTodo, at: 0)


            }
            self.todoArray = newItems


            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        }



}


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return todoArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        let todoLine = todoArray[section]
        return  todoArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let todoLine = todoArray[section]
        return  todoLine.dateLabel
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TodoTableViewCell
        cell.todoItemName.text = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].title
        cell.todoDescription.text = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].content
        cell.usernameLabel.text = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].username

        let  picNoteStringUrl = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].picNoteStringUrl
        let  userImageViewStringUrl = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].userImageViewStringUrl


        FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: picNoteStringUrl!).data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let picNoteStringUrl = UIImage(data:data!) {
                        cell.picNote.image = picNoteStringUrl
                        print("testpass",picNoteStringUrl)
                    }

                })


            }else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription,"555")

            }
        })

        FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userImageViewStringUrl!).data(withMaxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if let userImageViewStringUrl = UIImage(data:data!) {
                        cell.userImageView.image = userImageViewStringUrl
                        print("testpass",userImageViewStringUrl)
                    }

                })


            }else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription,"555")

            }
        })

            return cell
    }





    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {


        return true
    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "\u{267A}\n Delete") { action, index in
            print("more button tapped")
            let    ref = self.todoArray[indexPath.row].ref
            ref?.removeValue()
            self.todoArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let check = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "\u{2611}\n check") { action, index in
            print("edit button tapped")



        }
        check.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange


        return [check, delete]
    }



    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to organize your data by section first. I don't see that happening since you simply add all received items into one array.

Based on the screenshot you have provided and the project, it looks as if you are trying to display todo items by date where each section is for a different date. And as far as I can tell, your date value is in the `dateLabel` property.

If all of the above is correct, then you would need to convert the `dateLabel` property, which is a `String`, to an actual `Date` value so that you can work with the individual dates. Or, depending on how the date string is set up, you might be able to do the same thing by getting just the date component of the string. For example, if your date strings are like "2017-03-31 10:55am" or something, just getting the "2017-03-31" part should allow you to organize the todo items so that all items for the same date can be easily identified.

Once you do that, you have to set up some sort of a structure - if you go with date strings, then a dictionary might work - where you can identify all todo items for a given date. For example, if you have just the date extracted as a string (like "2017-03-31") then you could set up something like this:

```
var dates = [String]()
var todoItems = [String:[TodoList]]()
```

The above means that for one string value (which would be a date), you'd have an array of `TodoList` items. The `dates` array would be just a convenience so that you can sort the date strings the way you want.

Once you have that, you can modify your table delegate methods to get the count of items in `dates` to get the sections and the relevant `TodoList` for each row. Like this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return dates.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let date = dates[section]
    let array = todoItems[date]
    return array.count
}
```

Hopefully, the above makes sense :)

Comment: Happy to have been of help if that cleared things up for you :) If you need additional help do post the project and I'll help.

Comment: really thank you so much for advice I have edit question and add code Todolist()  - thank you again for your help and answer ^_^

Comment: Hello Mr. Fahim  I still have problem >> Here's my project file https://github.com/Pprangjung/AppDontForget/tree/master/AppDontForget >> TodoList.swift and TodoListTableViewController.swift --Thank you so much

Comment: @MaprangSakulrat I've modified my original answer to include more detail based on your project. Hopefully, this helps you figure things out. And if it does, please mark the answer as "correct".

Comment: Really Thank you for your advice and thank you for your help ^_^